# How do I plot P( U, V | C = c) in Python?

Tags: python, statistics, histogram, kernel-density

My ultimate goal is to get the values that will then be used to visualize "the maps" of

- `P(U, V | C = c)`
- `P(U | C = c) * P(V | C = c)`
- `|P(U, V | C = c) - P(U | C = c) * P(V | C = c)|`

Here is some information about the data that I have.

Both `U` and `V` are continuous RVs. `C` I believe is ordered discreet as it consists only of the following values and the order of those values matters, as well as 5 > 2 == True.

```
C = {2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Otherwise, structurally all 3 variables have the same metadata

```
class:  ndarray
shape:  (90,)
```

I know how to plot

```
plt.hist(U, bins = 5, density = True)
```

and

```
plt.hist(V, bins = 5, density = True)
```

But how do I plot `P(U, V | C = c)`? Or `P(U | C = c) * P(V | C = c)`? Or `|P(U, V | C = c) - P(U | C = c) * P(V | C = c)|`? How do I get at those probabilities for each of the datapoints?

Comment: Interesting question. In general this is a difficult problem, but given that you only want to condition on C, and C is discrete with just a small number of values, it is straightforward to take a brute-force approach. For each value c, select all (U, V) such that C = c. Now you have 4 subsets. For each one, construct P(U, V), P(U), and P(V), and anything derived from that such as P(U, V) - P(U) P(V). Now you have 4 sets of results -- each one is conditional on C. More general solutions are possible but this is enough to do the stuff you mentioned at least.

Comment: Incidentally if you are trying to assess how strong is the dependence of U and V, my advice is to look at mutual information, which is essentially looking at log(P(U, V)) - log(P(U)) log(P(V)) instead of P(U, V) - P(U) P(V).